# How can I use python packages from apk in alpine

Tags: python, ldap, lxml, alpine-linux

I installed py3-lxml (and py3-pyldap) and expect python(3) to be able to import the library. But the module was not found. Where am I wrong?

```
docker run -it python:3-alpine
/ # apk --no-cache --update add py3-lxml py3-pyldap
/ # python3
Python 3.9.6 (default, Jun 29 2021, 19:36:19)
[GCC 10.3.1 20210424] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lxml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml'
>>> import ldap
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ldap'
```

Answer (score 1):

So basically you have two possibilites:

- either you use the bare `alpine` image and not only install `py3-lxml` and `py3-pyldap` via apk but also `python3` itself.
- or you use `python:3-alpine` and install the additional packages yourself like this:

```
apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps build-base # only build deps
apk add --no-cache openldap-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev # runtime deps
pip install --no-cache-dir -r lxml python-ldap
apk del .build-deps # delete build deps
```

Or, to quote [Jakub](https://twitter.com/JakubJirutka), maintainer of alpines `py3-pyldap` package (huge thanks for the fast response):

> Hi, don't mix python installed from whatever source with Alpine python
> packages.
> Just replace python:3-alpine with clean alpine:3.14 image and install
> python3 using apk.